# EEG in matlab - Graph theory segmentation

Tags: matlab, signals

i have an [EEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroencephalography) dataset and I want to further examine it with Laplacian Eigenmaps. However, at the moment I want to find the local maxima and save into a new matrix all the different vectors that lie in-between two local maxima (see picture- i am looking for the black lines).  I use the `findpeaks` function in Matlab and I get a matrix with the peaks but from there I do not know how to move on. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I still cannot follow you. Please specify what data of which kind you already achieved and what exactly you are aiming for...

Comment: I think I got it. Nevermind my question! Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing a lot, but are you looking for something like:

```
%% some data
N = 4; % number of peaks
peakPositions = rand(N,2); % peak positions

%% difference vector matrix
diffMat = zeros(N*(N-1)/2,2);
actPos = 1;
for n = 1:N    
    diffMat(actPos:actPos+N-n-1,:) = ...
               bsxfun(@minus, peakPositions(n+1:end,:), peakPositions(n));
    actPos = actPos+N-n;
end
```

Example:

```
peakPositions =
    0.2630    0.4505
    0.6541    0.0838
    0.6892    0.2290
    0.7482    0.9133


diffMat =
    0.3911   -0.1791
    0.4262   -0.0340
    0.4852    0.6504
    0.0351   -0.4251
    0.0941    0.2593
    0.0589    0.2241
```

Comment: Oops, im sorry!I did not explain my problem correctly. Maybe now it is clearer what im trying to do. Thank you though very much for your answer!